# How to fix problem on import one custom component

Tags: angular

i try to simply import custom component , in other component but i have error 'Cannot find module'

```
Cannot find module 'src/app/Aliase/index' or its corresponding type declarations.

5 import { IndexComponent as AliaseIndex } from 'src/app/Aliase/index'
```

i have import in ngmodel

```js
import { CreateComponent as AliaseCreateComponent  } from './Aliase/create/create.component';
import { IndexComponent  as AliaseIndexComponent   } from './userJamesAliase/index/index.component';
import { ViewComponent   as UserViewComponent    } from './user/view/view.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AliaseIndexComponent,AliaseIndexComponent,UserViewComponent
```

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'Aliase', redirectTo: 'Aliase/index', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'Aliase/index', component: IndexComponent },
  { path: 'Aliase/create', component: CreateComponent },
 
];
export const userJamesAliaseRoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders<any> = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

i also change file `tsconfig.json`

```js
import { AliaseIndexComponent} from 'src/app/Aliase/index';

     
@Component({
  selector: 'app-view, [adHost]',
  templateUrl: './view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view.component.scss']
})
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {
      
  // @ViewChild(AdDirective,{static: true}) adHost!: AdDirective;
  id!: string;
  user!: User;
     
  constructor(
    public userService: UserService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
   ) { }
     
 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['userId'];
    this.userJamesService.find(this.id).subscribe((data: any)=>{
      this.user = data;

    });
  }
     
}
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.scss']
})
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {
       
  @Input() username!: string;
  aliases: Aliase[] = [];

     
  
  constructor(public aliaseService: AliaseService) { }
     
 ...
}
```

I need to import this component to dynamically load this second component, the renaming of the compose and is there a problem?

Comment: can you please share what has been written in `CreateComponent`/`IndexComponent` component.ts files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to trace problems:

```
tsc --traceResolution
```

Comment: i have  command  unknown

Comment: try to install TypScript globally: npm install -g typescript. If it still doesn't work you can try to restart the terminal or the machine. Try also this command: npm i typescript --save-dev